# Updating webpage info from socket (JSP)

Tags: java, html, jsp

im starting to get on web development and I can use some help with this issue:

Im trying to do a web table where I can follow changes in market values.To do this im using a java API created by the company that provides me with the data; this API connects through sockets to a gateway server on my company that receives this info directly from their market databases.

The java app receives the data in real time and every 5 minutes creates an .txt document on the server. This .txt document is then read by the html page using a JS script I found.

I now this is a really crappy way to update the table and I want know if its possible to get the data in realtime directly to the page using JSP.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the cleanest implementation would be:

1. Database that holds the values you wan't to show.
2. Scrip / procedure that calls the API and stores the values in your database
3. Your page reads the values from the your database.

I wouldn't go for a real time solution, because then you have to wait for the API call evertime your web page is loaded.

On the other hand, it's possible to parse an external webpage / api with php, and include it directly in your page. Without the database in between.
But again - Then you'll notice a slower responce, and make an unnecessary API call evertime your page is reloaded.

XML parsing with PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php